# The port is closed Error when calling serial class from a different form

Tags: c#, serial-port

I am writing a program to communicate with a device via RS232. 
My program would be a GUI to help a user program/configure the device.

It will have multiple forms.
to make things readable, I have created a separate class for the serial communication. 
I can Open, Close and connect to the selected serial port on form 1. However, if I go into form two and try sending a serial command to the port, the program throws an exception saying "the port is closed".

Can you please let me know what I may be doing wrong.

Serial Class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO.Ports;

namespace DM_Config_Tool
{
    class Program
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// The main entry point for the application.
        /// </summary>
        SerialPort serialPort = new SerialPort();
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            Application.Run(new Form_Connect());
        }

        public string[] Serial_ListPorts()
        {
            string[] portList = { null };
            try
            {
                 portList = SerialPort.GetPortNames();
            }catch (Exception)
            {
                return null;
            }
            return portList;
        }

        public bool Serial_Connect(string _serialPortName)
        {

            serialPort.PortName = _serialPortName;
            serialPort.BaudRate = 9600;
            serialPort.Parity = Parity.None;
            serialPort.DataBits = 8;
            serialPort.StopBits = StopBits.One;
            serialPort.ReadTimeout = 500;
            serialPort.Handshake = Handshake.None;
            return Serial_Open();
        }

        public void Serial_Close()
        {
            serialPort.Close();
        }
        public bool Serial_Open()
        {
            try
            {
                serialPort.Open();
                return true;
            }catch(Exception)
            {
                return false;
            }
        }

        public bool Serial_Send_Cmd(string _serial_TXData, bool _serialData_AddNewLine)
        {
            bool TXStatus = false;
            if(_serialData_AddNewLine == true)
            {
                try
                {
                    serialPort.WriteLine(_serial_TXData);
                    TXStatus = true;
                }
                catch(Exception)
                {
                    TXStatus = false;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                try
                {
                    serialPort.Write(_serial_TXData);
                    TXStatus = true;
                    serialPort.DiscardOutBuffer();
                }
                catch (Exception msg)
                {
                    TXStatus = false;
                    //serialPort.DiscardOutBuffer();
                }
            }
            return TXStatus;
        }

        public string Serial_Receive_Data()
        {
            string _serial_RXDATA = null;

            try
            {
                _serial_RXDATA = serialPort.ReadExisting();
            }catch (Exception)
            {
                return null;
            }

            serialPort.DiscardInBuffer();
            return _serial_RXDATA;
        }
        public bool Serial_GetStatus()
        {
            return serialPort.IsOpen;
        }
    }
}
```

Form 2:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace DM_Config_Tool
{
    public partial class Form_FW_Upload : Form
    {
        int form_Height1 = 379;
        int form_Width = 276;
        int form_Height2 = 419;
        string RX_DATA = null;
        Timer Timer = new Timer();
        Program Program = new Program();

        public Form_FW_Upload()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form_FW_Upload_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {


            Timer.Interval = 1000;
            Timer.Enabled = true;
            this.Height = form_Height1;
            button2.Enabled = false;
            button3.Enabled = false;
            //Timer.Start();
            //Timer.Tick += new EventHandler(timer_tick);
        }
        private void timer_tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            RX_DATA = Program.Serial_Receive_Data();
            if(RX_DATA != null)
            {
                Timer.Stop();
                textBox3.Text = RX_DATA;
            }
        }

        private void Form_FW_Upload_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
        {
            Form_Connect form_Connect = new Form_Connect();
            this.Hide();

            //form_Connect.Show();
            Application.Exit();
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Height = form_Height2;
            Program.Serial_Connect("COM4");
            Program.Serial_Send_Cmd("BLM\n\r",false);

        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            button2.Enabled = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Debug your program and be sure you open the port before reading data.

Comment: When using more than one form you need instances of the form.  See my two form project at following posting : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34975508/reach-control-from-another-page-asp-net

Comment: You'll need to spend more time debugging.  If you want a shortcut then delete all calls to Close().  And it is very, very important that you delete the Discard calls, they cause undiagnosable data loss.

Comment: @M.Hassan
thanks very much for your suggestion.

Comment: @jdweng: I tried changing the code according to what you suggested, however, I still got the same result.

Comment: @Fildor
I can communicate with the unit now after I've closed the existing connection and then connecting to the unit in form 2. However I need to communicate with the unit through the same serial port. How would I be able to see what comport was selected by the user in form 1 when they do the initial connect?

Comment: Track the status of ports and exclude open ports to be used by user. You may need to change portlist to be list of struct having name and status.

Comment: You to use the same instance of the Serial Port in both forms.  You can either pass the instance; or call a method from one form to the other so the same instance of the Serial Port is used.  See my two form project.

Comment: One problem I see is that your `Serial_Open` method silently swallows any exceptions and returns `false`.  And when you call `Serial_Connect` you never bother to check if the port was opened successfully.  Why return `bool` values if you're not going to use them?